# Orthocenter of $\triangle ABC $?

Tags: circles, triangles, conic-sections, coordinate-systems, locus

Let ABC be a triangle whose vertices are $$A(-5,5)$$ and $$B(7,-1)$$ . If vertex C lies on the circle whose director circle has equation $$x^2 +y^2 = 100$$ then the locus of orthocenter of $$\triangle ABC$$ is ?
I tried solving this by taking a few variables but I am having a hard time eliminating them .

Comment: consider the points in a sytem of coordinate which axis are orthogonal

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: in order to do what, exactly?

Comment: i think you got a better answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may notice that $A$ and $B$ are equidistant from the origin, and your hypothesis imply that $C$ lies on a circle centered at the origin through $A$ and $B$. By [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_line), $O,G,H$ are collinear and $OH=3\cdot OG$. Since $A,B$ are fixed and $O$ is the origin,
$$ H = A+B+C $$
lies on a circle centered at $A+B = (2,4)$ having radius $5\sqrt{2}$.

[image]

Comment: Don't get me wrong here but could you explain it to me how you came to the conclusion that H = A+B+ C ? I'm having a hard time understanding the last part .

Comment: @Tejus: We know that $O,G,H$ are always collinear, with a known ratio of distances. Since $O$ is the origin, Euler's theorem can be written in the form $H=3G$, but $G=\frac{A+B+C}{3}$, hence $H=A+B+C$.